# Visual Studio Code C# Intellisense Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I'm having problems with Intellisense not totally working with C#. For some things it does work (Ex: trying to have a using statement), and for other things it doesn't (Ex: Linq queries or in a startup.cs file app.{enter whatever} shows nothing). But for my other classmates it does show all of these for them. The green flame for Omnisharp says the server is running and my language is set to C#. Sorry, I don't exactly know the best way to give the Omnisharp log, its too big for a screenshot, and my first time posting. EDIT: Also nothing gets underlined when something won't work, I don't know if this helps but it's something I have also noticed happens for my other classmates when they are using VS code

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 1/16/2019, 8:30:58 AM
    Target: c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: C:\Users\{NAME}\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 12540

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 3 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.28307.145 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
            2: Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.28307.222 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
            3: StandAlone 15.0 - "C:\Users\{NAME}\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\msbuild\15.0\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.28307.145 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Project system 'OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem' is disabled in the configuration.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master' on host 9952.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj'.
c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll  c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectFileErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProjectFile(Boolean condition, String errorSubCategoryResourceName, BuildEventFileInfo projectFile, Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.TryAddAssemblyFromManifest(String pathToManifest, String manifestFolder, List`1 assembliesList, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.FindPotentialSdkResolvers(String rootFolder, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.LoadResolvers(LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.Initialize(LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.ResolveSdk(Int32 submissionId, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String solutionPath, String projectPath, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.CachingSdkResolverService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ResolveSdk>b__0(String key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.CachingSdkResolverService.ResolveSdk(Int32 submissionId, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String solutionPath, String projectPath, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectLoader loader)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader)

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attemped to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\LinqSkeleton.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: c:\Users\{NAME}\Documents\{NAME}\CSharp\MusicLinqSkeleton-master\Program.cs added to workspace
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what OmniSharp is, but based on the error that's being output here, it looks like there's something wrong with your project file; which could inherently cause some issues with your intellisense. That `InvalidProjectFileException` is the compiler trying to tell you that your .csproj file is invalid in some way. Is your code in a version control system of some sort that you could revert to a previous revision of your project and/or see what changed?

Comment: The intellisense problem still persists even when I make a new folder and do dotnet new mvc for it.

Comment: My full understanding of this is hazy at best, but I read over the warnings and errors a couple times and finally I figured out that (here comes some real technical lingo) whatever is looking for omnisharp or intellisense or whatever decides those things was looking in Visual Studio 2017. I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and reinstalled C# extension for VS code and now it works

Answer (score 0):

What helped me when I had the same problem was the comment from [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3049#issuecomment-521651905).

**Steps to fix the issue**

Open the file:

```
cd /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/Sdk
sudo vim Sdk.props
```

Find a line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
```

And replace with output of this command:

```
echo "<Import Project=\"/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Current/Microsoft.Common.props\" />"
# <Import Project="/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/Current/Microsoft.Common.props" />
```

Additionally, I removed the *obj* directory from project dir and run `dotnet restore` to make sure everything is fresh.

---

Another thing you could do is to install newest *mono*. You can find the instructions for your distribution on the [official download page](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/).